# Apache balancing cluster

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, load-balancing

I need to make an apache + tomcat reliable, high available cluser.
I've seen many docs how to make this archeticture:

```
    __________________________                        _____________
   |        Load balancer     | 1 ________________ * |     Tomcat  |
   |__________________________|                      |_____________|
```

But i need to make several load balancers. And how to organize this archeticture is question for me. Is there some articles how to make load balancer host reliable too ?

```
    __________________________            
   |        Load balancer     |  
   |__________________________|           
    _____________|____________                      _____________
   |        Load balancer     |*________________ * |     Tomcat  |
   |__________________________|                    |_____________|
    _____________|____________            
   |        Load balancer     |  
   |__________________________|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is not so clear. You did not say explicitly whether you want to have all load balancers are active or just make one active and others standby for failover only.

If you want only one active load balancer and the others will be standby, you need just to install an HA solution such as keepalived or heartbeat to assign VIP to one of the load balancers. Then, you need to direct all your traffic to this VIP. This VIP will be assigned to another machine in case of failure of the active one.

If you want to have multiple active load balancers, you need to do this on another level like directing the traffic using your firewall to multiple destinations (load balancers). I have done this using `DNAT` rule which will distribute the traffic based on clients source IPs. One clear limitation in this way is that you need to know or at least have some expectation of your clients source IPs.

Comment: I'm new to loadbalancing and HA. Thanks for this possible solutions - I will talk about them with my boss. The only one requirement about load balancers that I know - they should be available by one IP address. But I can't imagine how several hosts can be available under one common IP.

Comment: So, you can use only one VIP which should be assigned to the active node. So, you will have one active load balancer. The other(s) will be standby ready to take over in case of failure.